# Ubuntu backup script kills performance

Tags: backup, rsync, performance-tuning, mysql, ubuntu-8.04

I run a nightly backup, which takes about 1 hour. During that the performance is bad as hell.

It looks pretty much like this:

```
# DB dump
ionice -c 3 nice -n 20 mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --user=foo --password=bar DBname > dump.sql
ionice -c 3 nice -n 20 gzip -9 ... dump.sql.gz

# copy to new backup folder
ionice -c 3 nice -n 20 rsync -a /backup/path/files

# delete old backup folder
ionice -c 3 nice -n 20 rm my/old_backup/path/ -rf
```

I think the rsync is killing it.

Do you see any improvement?

Comment: The first thing you should do is determine **if** it's the rsync causing the problem.

Comment: I do think so. The DB dump doesn't take 1 hour.
Can I somehow add a simple log text to the console to see what is finished when?

Comment: This is total guessing, but... How are your disks?  I had a situation where someone else's server had RAID 5 with a dead disk, and it would DOS my dependent service every night during backups.